# didBeginContact not being called for one spritenode

Tags: ios, collision, contacts

didbegincontact is not being called for powerup token - other spritenodes work fine. For instance player (plane) contacts helicopter works fine. Player (plane) contacts power up token and nothing happens (no didbegincontact) call. I have changed the masks to the same as helicopter but it still doesn't work. Is there a limit to the number of node category masks or something? I have been stuck on this a few days now.

```
//zpositions
float playerZ = .08;
float enemyZ = .08;
float explosionZ = .08;
float tokenz = .08;

//category bit masks
#define playermask 1
#define enemymask 2
#define bulletmask 3
#define tokenmask 9

   //add plane
    SKSpriteNode *plane = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"jet"];
    plane.position = CGPointMake(160, 80);
    plane.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:plane.size];
    //plane.size = CGSizeMake(15,25);
    plane.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
    plane.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = NO;

    //collision configuration - need to fine tune later
    plane.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = playermask;


    plane.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = playermask | enemymask | tokenmask;
    plane.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = playermask;
    plane.physicsBody.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = YES;
    [self addChild:plane];

    plane.zPosition = playerZ;

    player = plane;

    self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0.0, 0.0);

    self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self;

    //////// TESTING TESTING TESTING ----- Delete After
    [self powerUp];
            temp.position = CGPointMake(160, 160);


    SKAction *makeHelis = [SKAction sequence:@[[SKAction waitForDuration:1.50     withRange:0.35],
                                               [SKAction performSelector:@selector(helicopterEnemies) onTarget:self]]];
    [self runAction: [SKAction repeatActionForever:makeHelis]];

    //method call for spawning power up tokens

    SKAction *makeTokens = [SKAction sequence:@[[SKAction waitForDuration:25.50 withRange:0.35],
                                               [SKAction performSelector:@selector(powerUp) onTarget:self]]];
    [self runAction: [SKAction repeatActionForever:makeTokens]];

- (SKSpriteNode*)helicopterEnemies
{
    //Helicopter setup

    SKSpriteNode *heli = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"heli"];
           heli.size = CGSizeMake(18,18);

    heli.position = CGPointMake(skRand(100, 250),
                                self.size.height-50);
    heli.name = @"helicopter";
    heli.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:heli.size];

    //need to work on these numbers to coordinate with the other sprites
    heli.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = enemymask;
    heli.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = enemymask | bulletmask;
    heli.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = bulletmask;

    heli.physicsBody.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = YES;
    heli.physicsBody.dynamic = YES;
    heli.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = NO;

    //useless except to show you could change this
    //heli.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = YES;
    [self addChild:heli];

    SKAction *moveDownThenDie = [SKAction sequence:@[
                                                     [SKAction waitForDuration:0.10 withRange:0.35],
                                                     [SKAction moveByX:0.0 y:-1600 duration:25],
                                                     [SKAction removeFromParent]]];
    heli.zPosition = enemyZ;
    [heli runAction: moveDownThenDie];

    return heli;
}

- (SKSpriteNode*)powerUp
{
    //Power token setup

    SKSpriteNode *powerToken = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"powerup"];
    //powerToken.size = CGSizeMake(18,18);

    powerToken.position = CGPointMake(skRand(100, 250),
                                self.size.height-50);
    powerToken.name = @"Token";
    powerToken.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:powerToken.size];

    //need to work on these numbers to coordinate with the other sprites
    powerToken.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = tokenmask;
    powerToken.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = tokenmask | playermask;
    powerToken.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = playermask;

    powerToken.physicsBody.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = YES;
    powerToken.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
    powerToken.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = NO;

    [self addChild:powerToken];

    SKAction *moveDownThenDie = [SKAction sequence:@[
                                                     [SKAction waitForDuration:0.10 withRange:0.35],
                                                     [SKAction moveByX:0.0 y:-1600 duration:25],
                                                     [SKAction removeFromParent]]];
    powerToken.zPosition = tokenz;
    [powerToken runAction: moveDownThenDie];

    temp = powerToken;
    return powerToken;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer to my problem... Dynamic was set to NO for the power up token object. This disabled spritekit from checking for collision detection on this object.

powerToken.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;